# Displaying user generated video in Django

Tags: python, django, video, video-streaming

I am making a web app in Django where a user clicks a button to create a unique video programmatically. The video should then display in their browser.

I have set it up so the created videos are uploaded to a model and assigned ids (videoupload object 1,2 etc).

How do I now tell Django which video file to play in my template for the user?

Comment: Did you do the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/)? It shows how to do such things by having URLs containing the object id.

Comment: Thanks I will look at this. I have been following a video course that goes through creating a blog and I am still not sure what the process will look like in my case.